# Rewrite rule not working for redirect in subdomain hosted in a subdirectory of the main site

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I am running a WordPress network.  This means there are multiple websites produced by one installation of WordPress.  Each website is a subdomain of the parent website.  WordPress handles the creation of subdomain websites through a wildcard subdomain entered into cPanel, which points `/public_html`, which is where WordPress lives.

This means there is one .*htaccess* file serving all subdomain sites.

My parent website is `www.doig.com.au`. My problem website is `tech.doig.com.au`.

I need to 301 redirect `http://tech.doig.com.au/venom-media.html` to `http://tech.doig.com.au/portfolio/venom-media/`.

Previously, I had the following in my *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tech\.doig\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=120]
|
RewriteRule ^venom-media.html http://tech.doig.com.au/venom-media/ [R=301]
|
RewriteRule ^services.html/feed http://tech.doig.com.au/services/feed [L,R=301]
```

However, this no longer works.

[This is my *.htaccess* file.](http://pastebin.com/E9xJHCS1)

Why is the `RewriteRule` not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tech\.doig\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=120]
```

You appear to be `S`kipping all of the relevant redirects when the HOST matches `tech.doig.com.au`, which would seem to be the opposite of what you are trying to achieve. As it stands, your redirect would only occur when the domain is *not* `tech.doig.com.au`.

It looks like your `RewriteCond` directive should be negated:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^tech\.doig\.com\.au$ [NC]
```

The same is also true for another domain block in your .htaccess file, however, several rules in that section redirect to the other domain so I'm not sure what the intention is with that one.

**For example:**

```
## SUB DOMAIN: sub1
# If the HOST is NOT sub1 (note the negated (!) condition)
# then SKIP the next 120 rules that apply only to sub1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub1\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=120]

# These rules will only apply when we are at sub1,
# since they would have been skipped otherwise
RewriteRule ^page1.html http://sub1.example.com/path/page1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page2.html http://sub1.example.com/path/page2.html [R=301,L]
:
RewriteRule ^page120.html http://sub1.example.com/path/page120.html [R=301,L]

## SUB DOMAIN: sub2
# If the HOST is NOT sub2 then skip the next 40 rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub2\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=40]

# These rules will only apply when we are at sub2,
RewriteRule ^page1.html http://sub2.example.com/path/page1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page2.html http://sub2.example.com/path/page2.html [R=301,L]
:
RewriteRule ^page40.html http://sub2.example.com/path/page40.html [R=301,L]
```

---

**EDIT:** The above still applies, however, you also have this block near the start of your .htaccess file which is possibly preventing all of your redirects from being actioned.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

That 2nd `RewriteRule` appears to *unconditionally* rewrite *all requests* (other than the root) to `index.php`.

Comment: I removed the line that skips the rules, so they are no longer skipped, but the issue remains.

Comment: I've just noticed, what looks like, an unconditional rewrite near the top of your .htaccess file. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Those rules are Wordpress rules.  I think they are correct.

Comment: They might be correct, but with them being at the top of your htaccess file they are essentially blocking all your other redirects. Your redirects should appear earlier in your htaccess file.

Comment: I moved those rules down to the bottom, but the URLs I'm trying to rewrite [301] are not being caught.  I've updated .htaccess in pastebin.  This website is a subdomain.  Wordpress is installed on parent domain.  This website is generated by Wordpress using wildcard subdomains set in cPanel.  The only way I can redirect URLs on the subdomain is to use the parent domain's .htaccess, and set a rewrite condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tech\.doig\.com\.au$ [NC]`.

Comment: However, I remember reading somewhere that you had to set how many lines of rewrites applied to the condition.  In English: `follow the next 120 rewrite rules, before you hit [L]`.  Is this true?  That's what I thought the `RewriteRule . - [S=120]` line was for.  Does this line literally tell the server to skip 120 lines?

Comment: You can't move _everything_ to the bottom of the file, as you have done. `RewriteEngine On`, for instance, must be at the top. As a general rule: redirects then rewrites. "set how many lines of rewrites applied to the condition" - this is not true. The `RewriteCond` directives apply to just the first `RewriteRule` that follows them - always. The `S` flag is short for `SKIP`, so yes, it does the opposite of what you are intending and _skips_ the next 120 rules. I think you can use `S`, but you need to reverse your logic, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: How do you set a `RewriteCond` to apply to **x** `RewriteRules`?

Comment: (I have deleted the **S** skip directive, so there's no need to negate the `RewriteCond` anymore.)

Comment: As mentioned above, you can't. "The `RewriteCond` directives apply to just the first `RewriteRule` that follows them - **always**." However, what you can do is `S`KIP **x** `RewriteRules` when the opposite condition is true (ie. negate your expression) - you need to reverse your logic - you still need the `S` flag in the first `RewriteRule` directive following the negated `RewriteCond` directive! I'll update my answer with more of an example.

Comment: okay.  So I've done that and the rewrite is not triggering.  e.g. http://tech.doig.com.au/online-resumes.html.  I've updated .htaccess on pastebin.

Comment: You'll need to include the `L` flag in all your redirects, otherwise the rewrite engine will continue to parse your file, possibly performing further rewrites. But many of the URLs you are redirecting to don't appear to exist - generating 404s?! This seems to be the case with the above URL, which redirects to `http://tech.doig.com.au/online-resumes/` - this does not appear to exist!?

Comment: Where do I include the L though?

Comment: The `L` flag (short for `LAST`) is a flag used on the `RewriteRule` directive... `[R=301,L]`. The same as you already have done for a few of the directives near the end of your htaccess file.

Comment: Does that mean I place the `L` on all of the `rewriterule`s for tech.doig.com.au.  I don't understand.

Comment: Glancing over your htaccess in pastebin - yes. As a general rule, you should always include the `L` flag on all _external redirects_ when using the `RewriteRule` directive. (The `RewriteRule` directive isn't just for external redirects, however, so it's wrong to say you should use it on all `RewriteRule`s.) You have also used mod_alias (`Redirect` and `RedirectMatch`) for some redirects - these don't take any "flags" (it's not in the syntax) - so you wouldn't apply it to these rules.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you have a look at my updated .htaccess in pastebin please?

Comment: What exactly am I looking for? `[L,R=301]` is the right idea - yes.  Although the fact that you have 3 x `RewriteRule ^portfolio/` in the same block would seem to suggest that you have a bit of cleaning up to do?